# Powershell Invoke invalid command output C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have short C# code which fires an invalid command using powershell.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInst.AddScript("abc");
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine(PSOutput);
}
```

Output is not printing anything. when same command fire using actual powershell  then following output is printed.

[image]

How can I get error output in C sharp code?

Comment: What is `abc` referring to?

Comment: this is just an invalid command, on runtime I am executing an exe file with full path , but it can happen that exe is not there. so wanted to print error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the errors, you can check if the powershell object [HadError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.haderrors?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) then look into [Streams.Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.error?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System_Management_Automation_PSDataStreams_Error) property of the powershell object and for each [ErrorRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), you can get the Exception, StackTrace, ToString, etc:

```
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var output = powerShell.AddScript("abc").Invoke();
    if(powerShell.HadErrors)
    {
        foreach(var error in powerShell.Streams.Error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** PowerShell provides multiple [streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for different purposes: Debug, Error, Information, Progress, Verbose, Warning. You can get the streams using [Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of your powershell instance.